# Setting Visual Studio (2022) Line number on/off through extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022

How do I turn "Line numbers" on or off in an extension I am making?

I am changing *something* but either Visual studio does not notice, or I am changing the wrong record. There is a setting Tools->Options->Text Editor/All Languages/General/Line Numbers but I cannot find it in the SettingsStore so I am trying out CSharp instead.

The code that does the change:

```
var readOnly = settingsManager.GetReadOnlySettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);
var writeable = settingsManager.GetWritableSettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);

var value = readOnly.GetPropertyNamesAndValues(@"Text Editor\CSharp")["Line Numbers"];
  // => value == 1
writeable.SetInt32(@"Text Editor\CSharp", "Line Numbers", 0);
value = readOnly.GetPropertyNamesAndValues(@"Text Editor\CSharp")["Line Numbers"]; // => 0
  // => value == 0
```

**Update**
I exported all settings (menu:Tools->Import and exportsettings) and searched through the resulting file. There was nothing looking like "Line numbers" even though there are several similar entries in the menu:Tools->Options.

Answer (score 1):

I am with Visual Studio 2022 17.0.1. When I export my settings there is a property **ShowLineNumbers**.

```
<ToolsOptionsCategory name="TextEditor" RegisteredName="TextEditor">
<ToolsOptionsSubCategory name="AllLanguages" RegisteredName="AllLanguages" PackageName="Text Management Package"/>
<ToolsOptionsSubCategory name="Basic" RegisteredName="Basic" PackageName="Text Management Package">
    <PropertyValue name="TabSize">4</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="ShowChanges">true</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="ShowLineNumbers">true</PropertyValue>
```